# How to update times of using the service of Laboratory for each patient in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table named "lab_master(visit_rank,pid)".
visit_rank: is the times of visit
pid: is the patient id

I want to update the column "visit_rank" with the value of number of visit start from number 1 for each patient. I have tried like below SQL code but it's not correct.

```
DECLARE cursor_visit_rank CURSOR FOR
  SELECT pid
  FROM   lab_master
DECLARE @visit_rank INT
DECLARE @pid VARCHAR(50)

OPEN cursor_visit_rank

FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_visit_rank INTO @pid

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN
      SET @visit_rank = 0

      UPDATE lab_master
      SET    visit_rank = @visit_rank + 1
      WHERE  pid = @pid

      FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_visit_rank INTO @pid
  END

CLOSE cursor_visit_rank

DEALLOCATE cursor_visit_rank
```

Comment: You should not be using a cursor here, this is a straight-forward set operation. How are you determining the order? Add sample data and desired results to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You want to count how many visits per person and store that?  Try this:

```
DECLARE cursor_visit_rank CURSOR FOR
SELECT pid FROM lab_master order by pid

DECLARE @visit_rank INT
declare @thisid int = 0
DECLARE @pid VARCHAR(50)
OPEN cursor_visit_rank
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_visit_rank INTO @pid
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        if @thisid <> @pid
           set @visit_rank = 0

        set @thisid = @pid

        SET @visit_rank += 1

        UPDATE lab_master SET visit_rank = @visit_rank where pid = @pid

        FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_visit_rank INTO @pid

    END
CLOSE cursor_visit_rank
DEALLOCATE cursor_visit_rank
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But not correct. The result of your code is update value of number of records of each patient but not numbering.

Answer (score 0):

Any time you find yourself writing a cursor, you should question your assumptions. There is almost no instance when you actually *need* a cursor, which would be very slow.

Instead you can do this in a set-based fashion, using a window function.

```sql
;
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
      count = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY lm.pid)
    FROM lab_master lm
)
UPDATE cte
SET visit_rank = count;
```

Alternatively you can do a self-join

```sql
UPDATE lm
SET visit_rank = lm2.pid
FROM lab_master lm
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
      count = COUNT(*)
    FROM lab_master lm2
    WHERE lm2.pid = lm.pid
) lm2;
```